# function not returning the correct value

Tags: python, function, python-3.6, filepath

I'm having issue with function nor returning the correct value. The function return path to the file depending on user choice. I've checked choice input, but no matter what choice I enter in only returns one value.

```
def pick_sql_version():  # might be redundant
    sql_year = ['2008', '2014', '2016']
    for i, val in enumerate(sql_year):
        print(i + 1, " SQL Server Management Studio ", val)

    sql_version = input("Pick the SSMS version: ")

    # depending on the sql version path might vary
    if sql_version == 1:  # SSMS 2008
        path = ''  # which value to use?
    elif sql_version == 2:  # SSMS 2014
        print (sql_version)
        path = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/120/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio/Ssms.exe"'
        print (path)
    else:  # SSMS 2016
        print(sql_version)
        path = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio/Ssms.exe"'
        print(path)

    return path
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: Use `int(sql_version) == 1` etc. Inputs are read as strings.

Comment: Don't use `int`; you aren't using any of the properties of an integer here, so just compare strings. `if sql_version == "1":`, etc.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't help but to write another version for you.
Using the power of `dictionaries` you can make your code far more readable.

Let us connect the key `"1"` with value `"120"` and the key `"2"` with value `"130"`. We use these to insert into the path using `str.format()`.

Finally by using `dictionary.get()` we can pass a default value and if user input is invalid (not `1` or `2`) it would use the value 120.

```
def pick_sql_version():  # might be redundant

    # create an easy list to pick from
    sql_year = ['2008', '2014', '2016']
    for i, val in enumerate(sql_year, start= 1):
        print("{} SQL Server Management Studio {}".format(i, val))
    sql_version = input("Pick the SSMS version: ")

    # depending on the sql version path might vary
    version_d = {
        '1': '120',
        '2': '130'
    }

    # If invalid path is chosen fall back to default (120)
    t='C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/{}/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio/Ssms.exe'
    path = t.format(version_d.get(sql_version, '120'))

    return path
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into `dictionaries`. Just a small question: why do you have back slash in the path?

Comment: @YuryStanev Because the path got too long with format(). It is easier to limit to 80 signs. I remade is slighlty. Maybe this is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

with `input("Pick the SSMS version: ")` you are reading your input as strings, this means that if you input `1`, you will get`'1'` and if you input `2` you will get `'2'`.

You should work around the problem by checking if your input is `'1'` or `'2'` (you can also transform your input into an `int`, as suggested in some comments, but I think it will create you only problems: for example, it will raise an error if you input something that can't be converted to `int`):

```
if sql_version == '1':  # SSMS 2008
    path = ''  # which value to use?
elif sql_version == '2':  # SSMS 2014
    print (sql_version)
```

Comment: Yeah, I've fixed it. It was a lack of attention on my part. Thanks .

Comment: It isn't really intuitive that 1 maps to 2008, 2 maps to 2014, etc. You might want to compare against '2008', '2014', etc instead.

Comment: @BrianHowell The inputs come from a menu that is printed before hand; it doesn't really have to be intuitive, because the labels are explicitly shown.

Comment: @chepner oh yeah I missed the menu. With that, it's probably less intuitive using the method I suggested.